# _TypeError (type 'newsPostDetails' is not a subtype of type 'newsPostDetails' )

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Getting error

> "_TypeError (type 'newsPostDetails' is not a subtype of type 'newsPostDetails' where   newsPostDetails is from package:iona_central/Screens/Admin/NewsPostDetails.dart   newsPostDetails is from package:iona_central/Screens/Admin/newsPostDetails.dart )" when running.

Firebase uploads work completly, but app has an exeption occuring.

> _getNewsPostDetails (place where error is occuring is line 3)

```
_getNewsPostDetails() async {
    print("_getPostDetails now running... ");
    await DatabaseService()
        .getNewsPostDetails(widget.newsPostId)
        .then((newsPostId) {
      setState(() {
        NewsPostDetails = newsPostId;
        print("Newspost Details = " + newsPostId);
        _isLoading = false;
        print("_isLoading now is false!");
      });
    });
```

getNewsPostDetails Code (Databaseservices)

```
Future getNewsPostDetails(String newsPostId) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('newsPosts')
        .where('newsPostId', isEqualTo: newsPostId)
        .get();
    final newsPostData = snapshot.docs[0].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    newsPostDetails? postDetails = newsPostDetails(
      newsPostTitle: newsPostData['newsPostTitle'] as String?,
      newsPostContent: newsPostData['newsPostContent'] as String?,
      date: newsPostData['date'] as String?,
    );
    print("getNewsPostDetails Complete");
    return postDetails;
  }
```

Comment: In the first snippet, line 7, you're using NewsPostDetails (wirh capital N), while in the second, also line 7, you're using newsPostDetails? (with lower N). Have you tried using a capital or lower N in both places?

Comment: As the error message indicates, you have two different `newsPostDetails` classes: one from `NewsPostDetails.dart` and one from `newsPostDetails.dart`.  While you likely are using a case-insensitive file system where `NewsPostDetails.dart` and `newsPostDetails.dart` both refer to the same file, Dart tools assume that they are different.  Fix your `import` lines to use consistent capitalization.

Comment: As also mentioned in the first two comments, I also think the error is due to the use of ```NewsPostDetails``` in your code and ```newsPostDetails``` in the database services. Make sure to maintain an uniformity. Let me know if that works out!